# Integrating Maven & Non-Maven Projects [using Android, Eclipse & Netbeans]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, netbeans

I have two workspace for my project's server side and mobile apps.

**Server side:**

I have 10+ Maven projects and 1 main project that use other 10+ projects by pom.xml. Also all these projects are developed by using Netbeans IDE.

**Mobile:**

I have an Eclipse workspace including 3 Android-Library project and 1 Android project and none of them are Maven project.

**I want:**

Create a project called like MyAwesomeProjectCommons, and put all common constant, utility methods etc. in this project and use this project both of Eclipse (non-Maven) and Netbeans (Maven) workspaces by using my SVN repo.

And my question:
Is this possible? If yes, how?